# Hosting a WCF service from a Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, http, windows-services

I have made a Windows Service that host a WCF service on `http://localhost:8080/SomeService`

The Windows Service is configured to run using the *NetworkService* account.

When I try to start the service, I get the following exception:

`System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not register URL`
`http://+:8000/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace`
`(see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details). --->`
`System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied`

What I want to do is to add some code to the service installer (inside `AfterInstall` for example) to give the service the proper rights.

How can this be done in C#?

**EDIT**

I know that this service will be installed on XP, Vista and Win7 machines, so I will need something that works on all these platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Try `LocalSystem` account. (filling remaining space)

Answer (score 0):

Try **"Run-as-Administrator"** when you launch your application